# Программно установить .apk

Tags: java, android

Задача: через приложение загрузить обновление с корпоративного сайта и установить
Решение: 
после того как файл закачан

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Когда запускаю появляется следующее сообщение:
"There was a problem parsing the package"

Подскажите, что не так или в каком направлении капать

Comment: А разрешена установка приложений из сторонних источников?

Comment: Да, установка из сторонних источников разрешена

Answer (score 1):

Одна из причин такого сообщения заключалась в том, что APK файл был скачан во временный файл без расширения и система отказывалась его устанавливать.

Решение заключалась в том, чтобы переименовать его (у меня был сразу перенос в папку downloads реализован) и от туда те же, уже переименованные APK замечательно устанавливались.

Простое штатное переименование не работало (есть отдельные вопросы-ответы на эту тему). Копирование осуществлялось этой функцией:

```
public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException
{
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try
    {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [этой доке](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) тире в имени пакета запрещено и надо заменить его на подчёркивание, т.е. должно быть так:

```
vnd.android.package_archive
```

Comment: Такой вариант не работает